# WPF: How do I create a Grid dynamically that scales?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a demo app, and I'm trying to set the grid size base on a selection from a combo box. The problem I am having is when a do a 2x2 grid, for example. It doesn't fill the grid; just a quarter of it. I've tried messing with the size of the rows and columns and also the control that goes inside but I can't get it to behave the way I want it to. The behavior I'm looking for is too evenly divide up space for the rows and columns; and then have a control fill the cell. When I resize the window I want the grid and the controls in each cell too resize with the window.

Here is my code:

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
short cam = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (_length * _length); i++)
{
    RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();

    //rowDef.Height = GridLength.Auto;
    //colDef.Width = GridLength.Auto;
    //rowDef.Height = new GridLength((this.ActualHeight / length) - 7, GridUnitType.Star);
    //colDef.Width = new GridLength((this.ActualWidth / length) - 1, GridUnitType.Star);
    //var converter = new GridLengthConverter();
    //rowDef.Height = (GridLength)converter.ConvertFromString("*");
    //colDef.Width = (GridLength)converter.ConvertFromString("*");
    Border border = new Border();
    border.BorderBrush = Brushes.White;
    border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);

    //rowDef.MinHeight = (this.ActualHeight / _length) - 7;
    //colDef.MinWidth = (this.ActualWidth / _length) - 1;

    rendererGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
    rendererGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);

    AxCVClientControlLib.AxCVVideo axCVVideo = new AxCVClientControlLib.AxCVVideo();
    _hosts.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost());
    _hosts[i].Child = axCVVideo;
    _hosts[i].HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    _hosts[i].VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    border.Child = _hosts[i];
    //hosts[i].Width = (this.ActualWidth / length) - 1;
    //hosts[i].Height = (this.ActualHeight / length) - 7;

    axCVVideo.CreateControl();
    axCVVideo.Camera = Convert.ToInt16(camCombo.SelectedIndex);
    axCVVideo.XResolution = 640;
    axCVVideo.YResolution = 480;
    //System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    //axCVVideo.XResolution = (int)rect.Height;
    //axCVVideo.YResolution = (int)rect.Width;

    if (axCVVideo.ConnectSync())
    {
        axCVVideo.Connect();
    }
    _axCVs.Add(axCVVideo);


    if (col == _length)
    {
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }

    Grid.SetRow(border, row);
    Grid.SetColumn(border, col);
    rendererGrid.Children.Add(border);

    //Grid.SetRow(hosts[i], row);
    //Grid.SetColumn(hosts[i], col);
    //rendererGrid.Children.Add(hosts[i]);

    col++;
```

Comment: I would try using two loops - one to create the row definitions, and one to create the column definitions.  I'm not sure how to programatically recreate "Width = *", but that's what you want, not auto.  Then worry about adding the controls once the grid is entirely set up.  Adding row definitions and column definitions and controls in the same step seems unwise.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I tried this. It seems to work great; thanks for the quick feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name="someRandomGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This will cause the grid to have two rows and two columns. The rows will always be half the `ActualHeight` and the columns will always be half the `ActualWidth`.

You can do this in codebehind if you really insist on it:

```
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { 
    Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) 
});
```

Etc. The number determines how the grid size is divided up. If one column is 1* and the other is 2*, the first one will get one third of the width and the second will get two thirds. If they're both 2*, they'll both get 2/4 of the width (a.k.a. 1/2). It adds up all the numbers and divides. A star without a number in XAML means "1*". If you add a dozen 1* rows, you'll get a dozen rows each of which will dynamically resize to 1/12 the actual height of the whole grid at runtime.

This is not exactly intuitive, but once you learn it, it makes adequate sense.

Comment: I have tried something similar to this. But the problem is it doesn't scale.

Comment: In what sense does it not scale?

Comment: When I resize the window to make it bigger, the grid does not get bigger.

Comment: When you resize the `Grid`, if you have the column definition widths and heights set to *, they will resize. But it's possible your grid isn't actually resizing when you resize the window. For example, if the Grid's own HorizontalAlignment="Auto", it will not resize to fit its own parent's width. If its parent has HorizontalAlignment="Auto", the parent will not resize. Can you share everything from the Grid on outward to the Window itself?

Comment: This is a constant issue with XAML: Everything sizes to its parent, and there can be a large number of parents.